# Can not set preferred domain after setting change of address in Google webmasters

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I have created a new website and have added and verified 4 variation of the website (with and without **www** for both **http** and **https**). I have set change of address for my old website in the google webmasters.

Now I want to set the preferred domain to one of these 4 variations but in the domain settings I'm not able to change the setting and I see this message:

> Not all options are available because of a Change of Address request related to this site.

This messages shown for all of the for variations of this domain.

Comment: I just ran into the same thing. Did this ever go away?

Comment: No, the error still exists. some people recommend removing the change of address domains but it doesn't look right to me. If you find any solution please tell me too.

Comment: If google has already picked up the change, it seems safe to remove the change notice. Not the most elegant way for them to handle this..

Answer (score -1):

> added and verified 4 variation of the website (with and without www for both http and https)

god, you don't seriously want to have four sites with the same content?!

All of site variants should be 301-redirected to the one, single one url-variant. For this url variant you should create the search console property.

If i were you, i would delete three of the four url variants from the search console. Is it not possible, create the new one, with only one url variant. Othe variants should be redirected.

Comment: well the redirects are set and working properly. I added the 4 variations because google webmasters recommends to do so. It recommends adding all variations and choosing one as preferred one.